# getData() is not called when using authentication type of PATH_USER_PASS

Tags: looker-studio

I have encounter a problem when I am trying to build a google data studio community connector. Specifically, everything works and I can see the data rendered on the explorer screen if I user USER_PASS option of authentication, but if I use PATH_USER_PASS it doesn't render properly. When I look at the stack trace it doesn't even show that getData() function is executed. Can somebody help me?

publishing the code below from manifest file and hit CONNECT and EXPLORE will successfully give one row of data.

There will also be success when I change nothing but the AuthType to USER_PASS.

However, it will break when I change nothing but the AuthType to PATH_USER_PASS.

Note I hardcoded things into my getData and getSchema so running this code doesn't need any user input. The processing of getting data is not bind in any shape or form to the authentication process. This demonstrates this is possibly one of Google Data Studio's bugs.

As I said, getData() function is not even ran when I switch to PATH_USER_PATH authentication method.

Any help will be appreciated!!!!

main.js :

```
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();

function getAuthType() {
    return cc.newAuthTypeResponse()
        .setAuthType(cc.AuthType.NONE)
        .build();
}

function isAuthValid() {
  return true;
}

function setCredentials(request) {}

function getConfig(request) {
    var config = cc.getConfig();
    return config.build();
}

function getSchema(request) {
  var fields = getFields(request).build();
  return { schema: fields };
}

function responseToRows(requestedFields, response) {
  return response.map(function(submissions) {
    var row = [];
    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field.getId()) {
        case 'student_name':
          return row.push(submissions.student_name);
        case 'student_age':
          return row.push(submissions.student_age);
        case 'student_school_year':
          return row.push(submissions.student_school_year);
        case 'submissionDate':
          return row.push(submissions.__system.submissionDate)
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
}

function getData(request) {

  var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(requestedFieldIds);
  
  // fake response from hardCodedData.
  var hardCodedData ='{"value":[{"__id":"uuid:3ab058df-5039-41cd-b16b-5c21f01bf60b","student_name":"Pieter Benjamin","student_age":21,"student_school_year":"Senior","select_student_school_year":"senior","__system":{"submissionDate":"2020-10-10T21:02:40.428Z","submitterId":"532","submitterName":"Pieter Benjamin","attachmentsPresent":0,"attachmentsExpected":0,"status":null},"meta":{"instanceID":"uuid:3ab058df-5039-41cd-b16b-5c21f01bf60b"}}],"@odata.context":"https://sandbox.central.getodk.org/v1/projects/124/forms/odata%20connector%20scheme.svc/$metadata#Submissions"}'
  
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(hardCodedData).value;
  var rows = responseToRows(requestedFields, parsedResponse);
  
  return {
    schema: requestedFields.build(),
    rows: rows
  };

}

// hard coded schema
function getFields(request) {
    var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
    var fields = cc.getFields();
    var types = cc.FieldType;
    var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;
    
    fields.newDimension()
    .setId('student_name')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

    fields.newMetric()
    .setId('student_age')
    .setType(types.NUMBER);

    fields.newMetric()
    .setId('student_school_year')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

    fields.newDimension()
    .setId('submissionDate')
    .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY);

    return fields;
}


function isAdminUser() {
  return true;
}
```

appsscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dataStudio": {
    "name": "ODK central API connector",
    "logoUrl": "https://getodk-a3b1.kxcdn.com/uploads/default/original/2X/3/381d364b5dd1069f6540bbd7a38ea48f11023ae9.jpg",
    "company": "UW Impact++",
    "companyUrl": "https://sites.google.com/view/udubimpact",
    "addonUrl": "https://github.com/UDub-Impact/OData-Connector/blob/master/readme.md",
    "supportUrl": "https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/issues",
    "description": "Get your data from ODK central",
    "sources": ["npm"],
    "templates": {
      "default": "1twu0sHjqR5dELAPyGJcw4GS3-D0_NTrQ"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 11/3/2020, this problem of not being able to use PATH_USER_PASS has been resolved. I didn't change any code but that option of authentication works now.